# How can i add a shape created in quartz 2d on the subview?

Tags: ios

I have created a shape using the beizer curve. Now i want to move that shape on the screen using UIPanGestureRecognizer. I am facing problems as gestureRecognizer is failing to call the function. I am unable to add that shape on the view. Here is the code.

```
 -(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0);
    CGPathDrawingMode mode = kCGPathFillStroke;
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0f, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0f);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, c1x1,c1y1);
    CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context,c1x2,c1y2,c1x3,c1y3,c1x4,c1y4  );//9pm to 3pm shape of upper curve

    CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context, c2x2,c2y2,c2x3,c2y3,c2x4,c2y4);//3pm to 9pm shape of lower curve
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, mode);
```